# Eclipse can't recognize my javax.ws.rs.core.Response object

Tags: eclipse

I have an object (`javax.ws.rs.core.Response`), but my IDE can't recognize it.

I cleaned and refreshed my project, but still not working.

[image: Eclipse can't recognize my object]

Comment: Does it say "No Completions Available" in red, at the bottom left corner, by any chance?

Comment: No, just said syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) all methods in Response are static. Your IDE does recognize the Object, but it has no instance method, so Eclipse will not suggest anything more than the nested classes.

EDIT:

I've found [another JavaDoc](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) for Jersey. Looks like it talks about slightly different (newer?) version of this class. Try to [download it](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0-m02) and try again.

Comment: I think it should still show the static methods, even for an instantiated object...

Comment: @GGrec I use Netbeans, but when I try for example String, I can't call static methods from instance. It's IMHO illogical to use it that way.

Comment: @DangeMask I refer to [jersey client example](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.17/client.html#d0e4692). In this example, it used `response.getStatus()`. So I'm confused.

Comment: @Ashkandi I've edited my answer. Try new version of the class.

Comment: @DangeMask This version `2.0-m02` of the class cannot resolve more classes. As you said, my IDE did recognize these objects so I will figure out the right way of using this Object.